# splitting messages in wso2 ESB

Tags: split, message, wso2-esb

Looking for a solution for the following requirement :

ESB will receive a big XML message (from JMS moslty)which holds around 10,000 records .
ESB will need to split the single XML message into multiple messages where each messages will hold 500 records and then do some  transformation + route it to destination queue.

Input to ESB : 1 XML message with 10,000 records

Output from ESB : 20 XML messages (each having 500 records)

Please suggest if there is a pattern for this kind of requirement. Using Iterate/Aggregator alone may not help to solve this  requirement.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume this could be possible using a smooks transformation. You'll find mor information about it on the wso2 homepage e.g.

http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/2011/06/perform-data-mapping-smooks-editor-wso2-carbon-studio/

Comment: Thanks Martin , had a look it mostly talks about mapping , but the requirement is bit more like splitting the messages, please point me if this kind of functionality can be achieved using Smooks.

Comment: According to the following page it's one of the use cases that can be achieved using smooks.  http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MILYN/Processing+Huge+Messages+with+Smooks There you'll find "Splitting & Routing:  Splitting of a huge message into smaller (more consumable) messages in any format (EDI, XML, Java etc.)".